# How to change a floating box that comes up when you press a key

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, nautilus-extensions

When you're on you Desktop and you press any key then a floating popup is comes up at right bottom corner of a screen:

[image: screenshot of that thing]

Comment: What sort of change do you want to make?

Comment: I want to get rid of it at all. I assume that I'll have to make an extension but I have no clue where to find a function that responds for this element.